# How to download multiple files from ftp using powershell

Tags: powershell

I already have a loop that list the file summary in the FTP directory. The $outputBuffer contains

```
/archive/20120806_141250.txt
/archive/20120806_142114.txt
/archive/20120807_090149.txt
/archive/20120808_090348.txt
```

I have a For-EachObject replacing /archive with the full ftp address:

```
$outputBuffer | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'archive/', 'ftp://ftp.test.com/outbound/archive/'
    }
```

My results is:

```
ftp://test.com/outbound/archive/20120806_141250.txt
ftp://test.com/outbound/archive/20120806_142114.txt
ftp://test.com/outbound/archive/20120807_090149.txt
ftp://test.com/outbound/archive/20120808_090348.txt
```

How could I add a line in this ForEach-Object statement to download each one of the files after I do the replace?

Answer (score 0):

```
$links = $outputBuffer | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'archive/', 'ftp://ftp.test.com/outbound/archive/'
    }
```

and then

```
foreach($link in $links)
{
Invoke-WebRequest $link
}
```

This should download the file in PWD

Comment: Does that really work?  The description for this new V3 cmdlet is "sends HTTP and HTTPS requests to a web service"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.credentials = new-object system.net.networkcredential("user", "password")
$outputBuffer | Foreach-Object {
    $filePath = $_ -replace 'archive/', 'ftp://ftp.test.com/outbound/archive/'
    #Adjust D:\local\ to be an actual folder.
    $fileDest = $_ -replace '/archive/', 'D:\local\'
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($filePath)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $fileDest)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:53 char:28
+     $webclient.DownloadFile <<<< ($filePath, $fileDest)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Replace the $fileDest line with '$fileDest = C:\test.txt' (minus the ' ' ) and see if, when it's all done, you have a file on your c:\ with that name, or if you still get the same error.

Comment: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Comment: If you need to login, add this line before the $output buffer line: $webclient.credentials = new-object system.net.networkcredential("user", "password")

Comment: Still getting an error. Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Comment: should the $webclient.DownloadFile($filePath, $fileDest) be $webclient.DownloadFile($uri, $fileDest)?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, because when you are using $filepath in the DownloadFile it is using ALL the string again.

Comment: Did it download properly to the hardcoded $filedest we tried?  If so, write-host $filedest in the loop and troubleshoot until it's right.

Comment: No, it is still giving an error when trying to download the files because it is trying to download "ftp://test.com/outbound/archive/20120806_141250.txt
/archive/20120806_142114.txt
/archive/20120807_090149.txt
/archive/20120808_090348.txt"

Comment: It is adding the entire string of text when trying to run the download so it is giving an error each time.